# How to avoid printing of Exception Id while printing Servlet Exception in doFilter()

Tags: java, exception, servlet-filters, unhandled-exception, servletexception

While throwing Servlet exception in Filter class doFilter() method, Exception Id is getting printed which is causing "Unhandled Exception" Veracode vulnerability. Below is my code.

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request,ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IO Exception, ServletException{
//some code
    if(//some condition){
          chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }else{
       throw new ServletException("Attack detected!");
    }
```

Servlet Exception is getting printed but it is printed along Exception Id which is causing veracode vulnerability.

Can you please help me solve this? Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see any printing going on there.  Please show ALL relevant details including logging, etc.

Comment: When the if condition is failing, I want it to throw a Servlet exception. And it is doing so. But not sure from where the exception id is getting printed

Comment: And we can't help you if you don't show the relevant logging information, call stack, etc.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.